# Ubuntu 20.4 KVM bridged network now working on guest

Tags: networking, 20.04, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am in the process of migrating a machine from Debian to Ubuntu 20.4.

Everything seems to be working fine other than I am unable to get KVM VM's to connect directly to the network. Switching to 'NAT' works, but the VM's provide services that need to be visible to the rest of the network.

Things I tried:
The traditional Debian way (this has worked on dozens of machines in the past): Update /etc/network/interfaces to include a bridge

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Restart the network (/etc/init.d/networking restart) then select the bridge in virt-manager and start the machine. No luck.

So I rolled back those changes and tried the macvtap option in the network source with the appropriate network interface, no luck there.

Next I found this page:
https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/creating-an-ubuntu-kvm-networked-bridge-interface/

I followed the directions to use netplan but had the exact same behavior as editing the network interfaces file.

Further down the page were options for command line setup so I tried setting it up manually:

```
nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
nmcli con down "Wired connection 2"
nmcli con up br0
```

The bridge shows up running the nmcli con-show command and it is active, but the same behavior on the guest.

After that I did ensure the bridge was visible using virsh:

```
virsh net-start br0
virsh net-list
```

Sure enough it's active, but does not work in the VM.

Finally I found my way into the network manager gui and set up a bridge using that. Same behavior. The host connects to the network using the bridge but the guest is just dead. dhclient does not get an IP address and the logs just shows no connection.

I did find a solution that indicated it may be a firewall problem on the host, but I verified the firewall was disabled.

So I am kind of stuck.

My preference would be to match the other machines configuration-wise and set up the bridge in /etc/network/interfaces but I am open to anything at this point.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of reading and testing I found the issue in my case.

It sounds strange but after running out of ideas I had read that one should not use bridging on wifi cards as they typically do not support bridging.

While this was a wired card I swapped in a card from another server that was working and it just worked! So the issue appears to be some sort of problem with that card!

Backed out all my experimental changes and things are running smoothly this AM.

Thanks!